# How to modify the content of a TemplateRef in Angular2+?

Tags: angular

How can i modify the text content, or the innerHTML of a TemplateRef?

i tried following on Stackblitz:

```
# component.ts

import { Component, TemplateRef,  ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild("test", {read: TemplateRef})
  public test: TemplateRef<any>;


  constructor(){
    // this.test.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "changed text" // <-- isnot working
  }
}

# html.html

<ng-template #test>
  <p>text content</p>
</ng-template>

<!-- to see if its working -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="test"></ng-container>
```

The goal:

I created a service which holds a given TemplateRef.
Then i can get this TemplateRef from other components via the service.
After got this, i want to change the innerHTML and render the Ref via a DialogboxService.
But i even failed to change the text content in the ng-template....

Answer (score -1):

**html**

```
<p #test > Some text </p>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('test') testcontainer: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>
```

you can change it in ngAfterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.testcontainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = "changed text"
  }
```

Or if you want to change by using function call

```
 changeText() {
    this.testcontainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = "changed text"
  }
```

Comment: I tested this previously, but how can i do that in my case when i have it in the ng-template?

Comment: May I know what is the condition to show the p tag? because ng-template is a virtual element and its contents are displayed based on conditions. So if we want to access a virtual element's template reference in the ts file, it will show error

Comment: Condition is following:
I use a dialog service, which displays the content text directly in a div. So when i want to have multiple lines, its not working. The dialogservice can handle also `templateRef`, so i tried to add a `ng-template` in `app.component`. to get access to it i added a templateService which `get/set` a `templateRef`. So when i could modify the `templateRef` in another service, i could insert the text is the `<p>` tag and display the `templateRef` in de dialogbox and the line break should work. a lot of work, just for a line break....